# Answer re-accepted but still -15 RP

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer, reputation-history, unaccepted-answer

Yesterday I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41696745/typeerror-validate-on-submit-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self/41697062#41697062) and the answer got accepted and upvoted. In my reputation list I got `+15`RP for an accepted answer but also `-15`RP for an unaccepted answer. Apparently the answer got accepted and unaccepted at the same time. However if I look at the post I see the answer got accepted. So I don't understand the reason for the `-15`RP.

[image]

Comment: Possibly they accepted, accidentally unaccepted, then re-accepted.

Comment: @Mithrandir That seems like the most likely thing, though it's weird that it doesn't have something like "[+15] accept [-15] unaccept [+15] accept" if it's that scenario.

Comment: @doppelgreener I agree with you here.

Comment: I had an answer to accept, so I did some science - it just showed the accept, without the first accept/unaccept...

Comment: Sometimes rep needs some time to relax, in a couple of minutes tho it should be back to normal. Over a day is long...

Comment: @RaisingAgent I thought so as well. However it has been like this since yesterday so I thought I might ask what's the reason.

Comment: What does your [reputation audit page](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) is showing for post 41697062? That's what matters for the actual reputation. If you see (15) there, it means you did get the reputation, and it's just a cosmetic issue in the reputation history.

Comment: @ShadowWizard In the reputation audit page there are two entries for post 41697062: (10) and (15). Also the overall RP on the audit page is 15 points higher than the one shown in the reputation history. Thx for the hint.

Comment: But when will the reputation history be revised and what is the actual reason for this?

Comment: So it's not a "critical" bug, i.e. your rep isn't affected, there's only a display issue in the reputation events list. This might be fixed by itself by some cleanup script, worth to check tomorrow if it's still showing wrong. As for why, I guess that somehow the "unaccept" event was processed before the "accept" event, which messed things up.

Comment: Alright I'll keep an eye on it. Thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a matter of both the unaccept and re-accept coming in at the exact same time and throwing the system off. A simple recalculation of your account fixed the issue.

Comment: This also should run daily, right?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It runs every 15 minutes, but only checks profiles which have been scheduled to be checked due to some event (like a deletion or undeletion, etc).

Comment: So without manual intervention, this would be fixed only on next reputation event?

Comment: @ShadowWizard All I did was delete the post and immediately undelete it so it would get scheduled for recalc. (Anyone can technically do it.)

Comment: @animuson Now the reputation points fit the expected. So recalculation worked. Meaning next time I experience this issue I would simply delete and undelete my post, right?

Comment: @mrleeh You can do that, yes. Then just wait 15 minutes and see if it corrects itself. In this case, you wouldn't have been able to delete this answer because it was accepted. But you can always just find aome other random post if you wanted.